# How to fix "item[key].toLowerCase is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a search field in my dashboard and I have get api in this api  have array and in the array I have objects so how I can do it in react what logic I should apply on it .

Here is the logic I apply on it but it returns error that

This is error:

```
item[key].toLowerCase is not a function
```

and this is logic i apply on it :

```
handleChange = event => {
    const lowercasedFilter = this.state.SearchResult.toLowerCase();
    this.state.data.bank_accounts.filter(item => {
    return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
      item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
    );
  });
    this.setState({ SearchResult: event.target.value });
  };
```

Comment: `item[key]` is not a string. Can you please tell how a single item of  array looks like?

Comment: `{bank_accounts : [ { id: 1 , item_name: 'bankOne'} , {id: 2 , item_name:'bankTwo'} ] }`
i want to add search functionality on item_name

Answer (score 7):

As you showed that your single item looks like

```
{bank_accounts : [ { id: 1 , item_name: 'bankOne'} , {id: 2 , item_name:'bankTwo'} ] }
```

Here there are two keys `id` and `item_name` so `item[key]` for `id` is number and for this it throw error. First check the `typeof` the value and then use `.toLowerCase`

```
handleChange = event => {
    const lowercasedFilter = this.state.SearchResult.toLowerCase();
    this.state.data.bank_accounts.filter(item => {
    return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
      typeof item[key] === "string" && item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
    );
  });
    this.setState({ SearchResult: event.target.value });
  };
```

**Note**: `filter()` doesnot mutate the original array. You need to store the result in another variable. like

```
const result  = this.state.data.bank_accounts.filter(....)
```

Comment: ok this code is not throwing any error but its not working when i enter any input my list items dosent changes

Comment: @SyedSadaifRizvi `filter()` doesnot mutate the original array you need to assign it to new variable.

Comment: its not working here is the code :

`handleChange = event => {
    const lowercasedFilter = this.state.SearchResult.toLowerCase();
    const result = this.state.data.bank_accounts.filter(item => {
    return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
      typeof item[key] === "string" && item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
    );
  });
    this.setState({ SearchResult: event.target.value });
  };`